# How to change backcolor of text when textbox is readonly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I am working on windows form application.i given my text box back color is green.then i changed the textbox read only property true.but while running the back color is not appearing,

i have tried a lot to find this,but no answer ..
if any help is very appriciable.

How can I change the backcolor of the text, when the textbox is made readonly
Thanks

Comment: `If TextBox1.ReadOnly Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If`

Answer (score 2):

Add

```vb
If textBox1.ReadOnly 
   Then TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Blue
End If
```

to the event handler of the desired event.

If you want to change the back color when the form is loaded just use

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   If textBox1.ReadOnly 
      Then TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Blue
   End If
End Sub
```

If you want to change the color after a button is pressed or any other event is fired just implement the event handler and change the color there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to code view and on the load function type in

```
TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red
```

Obviously where TextBox1 is you'll enter the designer name for the textbox.